# The new "You have x votes left for today" banner hangs around for 20 seconds

Tags: feature-request, user-experience, rate-limiting

There's a new banner when running out of votes for the day:

[image: The new banner is shown in the top middle of the screen, rather than around the votes buttons as before.]

I thought it made a lot more sense right next to the vote buttons, but I know there's a whole lot of effort and reasoning that goes into the style changes, so I won't just say turn it back. I do take issue with the time it takes to disappear for a few reasons:

1) It moves as you scroll, so if you don't click the `x`, it blocks out a portion of what you're trying to see.

2) The `x` isn't anywhere near the cursor at the time this notice is triggered. When you click the vote buttons, your cursor is all the way on the left edge of the screen, but the `x` is over on the right half, so it's really inconvenient to click when you're scrolling to the next answer.

3) It takes 20 seconds. This is a long time to read just 6 words, especially when one of the words is a number. The users who will see this notice are usually users who are using the site a sizeable amount, since they're seeing enough posts to run out of votes, thus they've probably seen the notice before, and they won't need nearly 20 seconds to figure out what it says.

For comparison's sake, the alert "Daily vote limit reached; vote again in xx minutes." pops up in the same place when you click the button, but only takes 5 seconds to disappear.

[image: A red box pops up in the same place with the text "Daily vote limit reached. vote again in 21 minutes.]

That feels a lot more reasonable.

I'd like to request that the time on the first banner get reduced to 5 seconds so that it's not so invasive.

Comment: _"...but I know there's a whole lot of **effort** and **reasoning** that goes into the style changes, so I won't just **say turn it back**."_ -- 1. Wasted; 2. Lack of; 3. just say it

Comment: I'm glad I don't vote enough for this to bother me, because it would be _extremely_ frustrating.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what problem this UI change solves or fixes. The best I can tell it is useless UI crap that simply distracts me and breaks my workflows. It appears to be the result of allowing developers to drive requirements. Useless bells and whistles that harm instead of improve the UX experience...

Comment: That isn't the only thing; the "delete" popup too, but then again I haven't left a question (tab) open long enough to see if it also took 20 seconds to close by itself.