# How to disable the tablet-like prompts after performing an action on the site?

Tags: support, user-experience

I'm having trouble finding an option to disable the tablet-like prompts after performing an action on the site. For example, after casting a vote:

[image]

There's no need to distract me when things are successful. I prefer dark and silent cockpits. I also don't use a tablet. I want to disable the distraction.

My Settings preferences only include the standard Keyboard, Navigation, Custom Questions and Advertisements. I don't see a setting for unneeded prompts.

How do I disable the prompts?

---

And just for fun. It looks like I am on a porn site competing for my clicks:

[image]

Comment: I don’t recognise that prompt. Is it new?

Comment: It is new @Tim, just tried it. Looks very out of place on a desktop, at the top of the page.

Comment: I don't think SE will create a way to do this, and hope there's a friendly JavaScript programmer somewhere that feels like creating a userscript for it.

Comment: The downvote tooltip when under the rep threshold now uses this new prompt.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378125/the-new-you-have-x-votes-left-for-today-banner-hangs-around-for-20-seconds

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I wouldn't mind trying to create a userscript for it if I could see the inspect element for these elements. Unfortunately seems like a lot of work to see that prompt for me

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton See my answer below.

Comment: adblock should work... but... i'd rather them just not be annoying. I'd hate to block it then not get a notification when i've only got a few votes left.

Answer (score 2):

It is highly unlikely that we will ever get the option to disable such messages; we've never been able to turn these off before.

However, one can write a userscript that targets this information to block it. However, because it is inserted via JavaScript, this will most likely require a JavaScript userscript to counter it, as a CSS userscript will typically only apply its changes on page-load:

[image: browser tools screenshot of inserted div]

(ignore the highlighted line in this image. The actual message div is the `div class="grid--cell"` one a few lines up)

I did try to block this with Stylus and it was unsuccessful (I believe because it was inserted after page load via JS).

Here is the JS function that stretches its legs whenever this action occurs (from `/content/Js/full.en.js?v=30556cc8faea`):

```js
    D = function(e, t, n) {
        var i = e.text().indexOf("undelete") > -1;
        if (n && n.Success)
            if (e.html(n.Message), e.addClass("load-tooltip-on-hover"), n.NewScore < 0) {
                var o = $(".question:has(a[id='delete-post-" + t + "'])").length > 0,
                    a = o ? ".question, div.answer" : "#answer-" + t;
                R($(a), !i)
            } else S(e, i ? "Your undelete vote has been recorded" : "Your delete vote has been recorded");
        else {
            var r = n && n.Message ? n.Message : i ? "A problem occurred during undeletion" : "A problem occurred during deletion";
            k(e, r)
        }
        StackExchange.realtime.pauseQuestionNotifications = !1
    }
```

Comment: If I get some time, I may try to work on a userscript for this. A problem I see is that I'm not sure if actual (useful) error messages use the same structure, and I wouldn't want to block important information. To get around that, you could target elements with the words "Your delete vote has been recorded", and then transverse to the `.s-toast` parent and block that. I also have no way to test the userscript :/

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes, I bet other messages use the same classes. Let me add the most immediate JS that plays a part.

Comment: Digging around the Stack Exchange code is often easier when looking at the [unminified code](//dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.js). That shows `S` is really `showInfoMessage`, which is just a wrapper for `StackExchange.helpers.showToast()`. So, you can do what's desired by waiting until `StackExchange.helpers.showToast()` exists, then creating a wrapper for it that filters out the messages you desire to not see, or just add a `transientTimeout` property (in ms) to the options Object. If you want to know what options are available, the `showToast()` code is in [stub.js](//dev.sstatic.net/Js/stub.js).